# Reverse SSH "Connection closed by ::1"

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh

I try to establish a remote ssh connection.

I tried to connect "Remote" with `ssh -fN -R 10110:localhost:22 GatewayUser@GatewayHost`

and "Gateway" with `ssh -p10110 RemoteUser@localhost`

I got the response on the Gateway Console `Connection closed by ::1`

running it with -v `ssh -v -fN -R 10110:localhost:22 GatewayUser@GatewayHost`

produces that response in the Remote-Console

```
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 2 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 10110, originator ::1 port 48481
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22) in progress, fd=4
debug1: channel 0: new [::1]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug1: channel 0: connected to localhost port 22
debug1: channel 0: free: ::1, nchannels 1
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
```

PS: a SSH connection from Remote to Gateway is working

Many thanks in advance!

__

Here the console-output when connecting from the gateway machine`emanuel@UbuntuServer:~$ ssh -vvv -p10110 pi@localhost`

```
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 10110.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emanuel/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emanuel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emanuel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emanuel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emanuel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emanuel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emanuel/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emanuel/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [localhost]:10110
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[localhost]:10110" from file "/home/emanuel/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by ::1
emanuel@UbuntuServer:~$
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Is your `sshd` running on your machine?

Comment: `sshd` is running. I want to control my raspberry pi with ssh. I use an UMTS stick on the raspberry. Thus I think I need a reverse ssh tunnel. I can connect the raspberry with the Linux server, but reverse ssh is not working.

Comment: that makes sense. Can you run also the `ssh -vvv -p10110 RemoteUser@localhost` in debug mote from Gateway?

Comment: "::1" is IPv6-speak for "localhost"

Comment: @Jakuje : I run it as you intended and put the console output into the question. It looks that we're on the right way to find the problem. What do you think can I improve or change to make it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is: Crate a ssh connection from the raspi to the gateway, and forward the  *:10110 from the gateway to 127.0.0.1:22 on the raspi. 
Then you connect to port 10110@localhost, which may in some configurations use the ip6-address (::1) which has no tunnel behind it. sshd then closes the connection.
Try

```
ssh -4 -p10110 pi@localhost
```

This should get you one step further.
If you have problems finding the correct key (ssh stops after a certain amount of checked keys) then disable pubkeyauth with

```
ssh -oPubkeyAuthentication=no -4 -p10110 pi@localhost
```

Comment: I tried both, but I got in both cases:  `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: now it works. Solution was adding the `-4` In my case, I made the mistake when I tried some things to delete the hostly files. Thank you very much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Your `ssh` client seems to connect to your `sshd` via IPv6. Does `sshd` listen on IPv6 addresses ?
Add this line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart `sshd`:

```
ListenAddress ::
```

Or you can force IPv4 connection with `ssh -4` argument.

Comment: I add the line and got a failure. But this was already in the file: # Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0

Comment: @Emanuel: Which failure ? Do you see `sshd` binding on IPv6 addresses with `netstat` ?

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo service ssh start
[....] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 89: Bad configuration option: ListenAdress
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
 failed!`

Comment: @Emanuel Check twice : you mispelled "Address".

Comment: I corrected "Address". I tried to force the IPv4 Connection by typing:   `ssh -4 -p10110 pi@localhost`, now I get the failure `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` What must be written if I run the command netstat?

Comment: thank you, I solved it as described below. Your solution was correct.